# Adding an If inside an update statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add an IF clause inside an update statement. Thought this was easy, but seems it isn't.

This is the way it is. It's inside a stored procedure.

```
FETCH cur1 INTO procId, procType, procVals, procLen, procUpdated, procPrivate, procRegional;

    IF done THEN
      LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;

    UPDATE scores t1
        JOIN scores t2
        ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.id, t2.vals)
        SET t1.private = t1.private+1,
        IF procType = 3 THEN // Problem lies here
             t1.regional = t1.regional+1;
            ELSE IF procType = 4 THEN
             t1.otherCol = t1.otherCol+1;
          END IF;
    WHERE t2.id = procId;
```

I'm stuck with the `IF` in there. Apart from the first `SET`, I also need to `Update` another column with the `IF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE scores t1
JOIN scores t2
ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.id, t2.vals)

SET t1.private = t1.private+1 
t1.regional = IF (procType = 3, t1.regional + 1, t1.regional)
t1.otherCol = IF (procType = 4, t1.otherCol + 1, t1.otherCol)
WHERE t2.id = procId
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE scores t1
JOIN scores t2
ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.id, t2.vals)
SET t1.private = t1.private+1,
    CASE  procType 
    WHEN 3  THEN t1.regional = t1.regional+1
    WHEN 4  THEN t1.otherCol = t1.otherCol+1
    END as Col
WHERE t2.id = procId
```

Comment: The error it throws is at `SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE procType` just where the `CASE` begins.I've tried everything I could.

Comment: The sql works perfect without the `case` or `If` part. I decide to add the `CASE` only this evening.

Answer (score 1):

It would be simplier to break them into 2 separate update statements, because you are updating to different fields

```
IF procType = 3 THEN
    UPDATE scores t1
        JOIN scores t2
        ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.id, t2.vals)
    SET t1.private = t1.private+1,
     t1.regional = t1.regional+1;
    WHERE t2.id = procId;

ELSE IF procType = 4 THEN

    UPDATE scores t1
        JOIN scores t2
        ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.id, t2.vals)
    SET t1.private = t1.private+1,
        t1.otherCol = t1.otherCol+1;
    WHERE t2.id = procId;
```